# How to add armeabi so lib to Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I have Unity project just using android plugin to process In App Purchase. The IAP sdk using armeabi rather than armeabi-v7a. I copied armeabi folder to Unity\Assets\Plugins\Android\libs and Unity automatically include in to armeabi-v7a in apk. 
Is it possible to tell Unity to keep armeabi (but not armeabi-v7a)?

Comment: Have you tried to set it in the PlayerSettings?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt work. There is only ARMv7 and X86 in player Settings.

Comment: @nguyentran, can you explain are you using Unity's NEW (totally fantastic) IAP system? ie, this one: https://unity3d.com/services/analytics/iap  or do you mean something else?

Comment: Note that instruction sets are only relevant to native code. Unity IAP only has Java code.

Comment: @JoeBlow thank for your information. I need to support IAP for kind of Chinese market. So, I should write my own plugin. Here the market http://dev.10086.cn/datau/modules/views/introduction/index.html?menu=sdk

Comment: Ni Hao, can you just help me I'm confused:  question, are you using UNITY'S IAP SYSTEM, at all ?

Comment: Hi, Its great if I can understand Chinese: ).
I am using plugin to communicate from unity to android. The IAP SDK is using native lib which i need to integrate to unity. The issue is that IAP SDK is not support for armeabi-v7a. It works only with armeabi. The unity seem alway create armeabi-v7a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Unity do you use? I don't know about old versions, but [Unity 5 does not support armeabi, just armeabi-v7](http://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements)